# new Worker() will only be bundled if passed a String

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, web-worker

I'm trying out web workers to run a time-consuming data analysis script in my Angular 8 app, but I'm having some trouble bundling the worker. I'm looking for help to figure out what I'm missing.

I have generated a new worker for my project using the schematics included with Angular-CLI 8.0.2:

```
ng g webWorker suggestions --project=my-project
```

This generates a new `suggestions.worker.ts` and `tsconfig.worker.ts`, and updates my `tsconfig.app.json`,  `angular.json` and `package.json`. These look OK to me, but I can provide details if needed.

I have moved my `suggestions.worker.ts` to the same folder as the service that will instantiate the worker. The function instantiating the worker looks as follows:

```
async calculateSuggestions<T>(
    data: T[]
): Promise<Suggestions<T>> {
    const worker = new Worker('./suggestions.worker', {
      type: 'module',
    });

    const result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
        resolve(data);
      };

      worker.onerror = ({ error }) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    }) as Promise<Suggestions<T>>;

    worker.postMessage({
      data: data
    });

    return result;
}
```

However, when I build my project, the following warning and error appear:

```
WARNING in new Worker() will only be bundled if passed a String.

ERROR in chunk suggestions-suggestions-module
suggestions-suggestions-module.js
{..} \node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js! {..} \src\app\extractor\
No template for dependency: ConstDependency
```

My guess is that I'm not instantiating the `Worker` correctly, causing the bundling process to fail.

The warning seems to indicate that I should pass a `String` to the `Worker` constructor, but I am already doing so.

Further, the path behind the exclamation mark on line 3 of the Error is actually two folders above where I store my service and my worker files. Maybe this is a hint?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by downgrading to angular-cli@8.0.1. Still not sure about the root cause of the issue.

Comment: This isn't a solution, but a temporary work around.  The problem still exists in 8.1.3

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14776#issuecomment-516998921, so just add the second parameter like below

```
new Worker("file path", { type: "module" });
```

Comment: The second param `{ type: 'module' }` had already been added by @thijsfranck ...Same problem for me. I've the Warning "Compiled with warnings": `in new Worker() will only be bundled if passed options that include { type: 'module' }.`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid

```
... will only be bundled if passed options that include { type: 'module' }.. "
```

add

```js
new Worker('./testworker.worker', { type: "module" });
```

To avoid

```
No template for dependency: ConstDependency
```

- Check if there is webpack version mismatch
- See the output of `node ls`. There should be two different versions of *webpack@4.x.x*
- To fix this either remove your webpack dependency from package.json or try `npm prune`
- Remove the 'node_modules' folder and 'package-lock.json'
- Run `npm i`
- Run `ng serve` or `ng build`